# CustomConfigObj(file_path, raise_errors=True) is unable to preserve double quotes of the string values of the input file

Tags: python-3.x, config

Code:

```
from configobj import ConfigObj
class CustomConfigObj(ConfigObj):
    def interpolate(self, configspec=None):
        """Override the interpolate method to preserve double quotes."""
        # Do not remove surrounding quotes
        pass

def modify_vmx_file(file_path, new_properties):
        config_dict = CustomConfigObj(file_path, raise_errors=True)
        print(config_dict)
        # Modify the properties
        for property_name, property_value in new_properties.items():
            config_dict[property_name] =str(property_value)
            print(config_dict[property_name])

        config_dict.write(config_file)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    new_properties={
                "ide0:0.deviceType": "cdrom-image",
                "ide0:0.fileName": "",
                "ide0:0.present": "TRUE"
                }
    modify_vmx_file("/home/santhosh/sujata.vmx",new_properties)
```

The file sujata.vmx contains :

```
.encoding = "UTF-8"
config.version = "8"
virtualHW.version = "13"
nvram = "vHMC39.nvram"
pciBridge0.present = "TRUE"
svga.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge4.functions = "8"
pciBridge5.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge5.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge5.functions = "8"
pciBridge6.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge6.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge6.functions = "8"
pciBridge7.present = "TRUE"
pciBridge7.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge7.functions = "8"
vmci0.present = "TRUE"
hpet0.present = "TRUE"
```

The code is able to replace desired values but it removes double quotes from all the string values of the input file.

Any leads on this to solve this problem?